# Правильно ли составлена UML диаграмма классов?

Tags: классы, uml

Отношения между классами:

1. В классе BaseDate используется объект класса Date
2. В классе config используется объект класса BaseDate
3. ContentVeiveng содержит объект класса BaseDate и config

Правильно ли нарисовал UML диаграмму классов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий так как основан на мнении, нежели чем на фактах. Для кого правильно, с какой точки зрения и другие уточняющие вопросы (и ваш ответ на них) помогут нам понять что вы имеете в виду. Так как вы здесь впервые, рекомендую прочитать http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic о том на какие вопросы вам здесь могут ответить, и как лучше их задавать для получения ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно. Связь с ромбом на конце означает агрегацию, а не использование.

Из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.90.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F)

> Агрегация — это разновидность ассоциации при отношении между целым и его частями. Как тип ассоциации агрегация может быть именованной. Одно отношение агрегации не может включать более двух классов (контейнер и содержимое).
>
> Агрегация встречается, когда один класс является коллекцией или контейнером других. Причём по умолчанию, агрегацией называют агрегацию по ссылке, то есть когда время существования содержащихся классов не зависит от времени существования содержащего их класса. Если контейнер будет уничтожен, то его содержимое — нет.
>
> Графически агрегация представляется пустым ромбом на блоке класса, и линией, идущей от этого ромба к содержащемуся классу.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.
Честно говоря думал, что использование одного объекта внутри другого - это и есть агрегация.

Не подскажите, как оформить правильно?

Comment: я не могу подсказать, так как не знаю, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать. и главное зачем вы это делаете.

Comment: Практика в колледже) Окей, объясню подробно.
1. Класс Data - в нем содержатся свойства для подключения к MySQL;
2. Класс BaseData - содержит некие методы для работы с MySQL;
3. Класс Config - просто методы :)
4. Класс ContentViewing - методы выводящие некий контент.
Собственно, все это и так видно на скриншоте.

Теперь по логике: в программе сразу создается объект класса Data. После чего этот объект (а с ним все свойства класса) передаются через конструктор в в класс и остается с нем для дальнейшего использования. Все мы подключились к бд.
Дальше работаем с объектом класса BaseData

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.